# CreateFile crashes... GetLastError returns 4235960

Tags: c, winapi

As the title says I'm having a problem with CreateFile() that just doesn't make sense to me.  I'll admit it's been over ten years since I've done any programming on Windows so maybe I just missed something simple...

```
int makeButtons(HWND main_window) { 

HRESULT ec;
TCHAR config_file[MAX_PATH];
LPSTR config_folder;
HANDLE config_file_handle;
int i;

ec = SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,NULL,SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT,config_file);
if (ec != S_OK) {
    DisplayError((LPTSTR)"ec = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile,0,NULL,config_file)", ec);
    return -1;
}

i = (lstrlen(config_file)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
config_folder = (LPSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,i);
StringCbCat(config_folder,i,config_file);

StringCbCat(config_file,MAX_PATH,"\\Flipperbuilt\\Sidebar\\config.data");
MessageBox(NULL,config_file,"here",MB_OK);
config_file_handle = CreateFile(config_file,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
if (config_file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    MessageBox(NULL,"here","yep",MB_OK);
    DisplayError((LPTSTR)"CreateFile(config_file,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL)",GetLastError());
}
else {
    CloseHandle(config_file_handle);
}

LocalFree(config_folder);  
return 0;
```

}

All the MessageBox() calls are pretty much just debugging stuff at the moment... trying to make sense of where it's crashing.  The DisplayError() call is to another function that formats and displays the error code from GetLastError() and I know for sure it works properly.  If I leave out the MessageBox() before the DisplayError() it crashes... with the MessageBox() call before I get the 4325960 from GetLastError().

Any ideas?!?

Thanks!!

Comment: You did not show `DisplayError`. Why are you using `TCHAR`? Don't do that. Use wide characters throughout. Is your program Unicode? Your cast when calling `DisplayError` is dubious. If `LPTSTR` is pointer to wide char, then the cast won't change the fact that you pass `const char*`. Why is `DisplayError` receiving a modifiable string. Frankly, unless you are all over these details, C is the wrong language for you.

Comment: Show us DisplayError, maybe the crash in in that function.

Comment: You must not call any other function in between the failing function and GetLastError! Otherwise, you might get a garbage error code from the function you called in between. Edit: that's not necessarily *the* problem, and it's not even necessarily a problem *right now*, but it's a potential problem.

Comment: Please include a stack trace of the crash. That will help identify where the crash is.

Comment: First off I would like to thank you all for your input.  I would like to add the reason I haven't programmed Windows for so long is I have been running Linux and have made several worthwhile personal applications using Qt libraries so I have a pretty good understanding of C and C++... although I'll admit I have much to learn yet.  I have considered the MessageBox call before the GetLastError could be causing problems.  I was more or less interested in what error it would report so I would know which one to check for.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND would be the only error that would be returned if the file doesn't exist... or would ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND also be possible since the path doesn't even exist at the time.  I plan to simply check the error code and create directories and such as needed until I have the file in place.  I am not using unicode... as far as TCHAR... it's simply following the example I found.

Comment: I tried to add the DisplayError routine here, but it's too long for a comment (32 characters too long).  I do know it works for the most part having tested it with some bad calls already although it's not perfect as some have pointed out.  I guess what I'm really after is what errors I should expect to receive if the file and path don't exist at the moment.  Thanks all again... I believe I'll dig up my Programming Windows book and review the basics.

Comment: I've done a bit of looking at the SDK... if TCHAR and LPTSTR are automatically set to 8 or 16 bit depending on if UNICODE is defined or not why not use TCHAR?  I understand a const char* would be 8 bit and would cause a problem on a UNICODE machine and I have a problem there, but why not should I not use TCHAR?!?

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty stupid...  As Michael Walz suggested my problem was with the DisplayError routine.  I had an extra variable in the list in a call to StringCchPrintf() that didn't have any formatting (%s) information associated with it (somewhere along the line I made changes to it since it worked last and didn't realize it!!)  Thanks again for everyone's input.

```
int makeButtons(HWND main_window) { 

HRESULT ec;
TCHAR config_file[MAX_PATH];
LPTSTR config_folder;
HANDLE config_file_handle;
int i;

ec = SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,NULL,SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT,config_file);
if (ec != S_OK) {
    DisplayError("ec = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile,0,NULL,config_file)", ec);
    return -1;
}

i = (lstrlen(config_file)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
config_folder = (LPSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,i);
StringCbCat(config_folder,i,config_file);

StringCbCat(config_file,MAX_PATH,"\\Flipperbuilt\\Sidebar\\config.data");
config_file_handle = CreateFile(config_file,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
if (config_file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    DisplayError("CreateFile(config_file,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL)",GetLastError());
}
else {
    CloseHandle(config_file_handle);
}

LocalFree(config_folder);  
return 0;
}

void DisplayError(const char* lpszFunction, DWORD dw) { 
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
LPTSTR error_string_in = TEXT((LPSTR)lpszFunction);
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL );
lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,(lstrlen(error_string_in)+(lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + 10)) * sizeof(TCHAR));
StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),TEXT("%d: %s"),dw, lpMsgBuf);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, error_string_in, MB_OK);

LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
return;
}
```

Anything else I have missed or need to study up on?!?  As I've said before I do have a decent understanding... just haven't mastered the details.